Bull MQ NestJS error removing job from queue
I'm using Bull in a Nestjs-App for multiple tasks, one of them is running scheduled jobs with a delay. When a schedule needs to be updated or deleted, the corresponding jobs need to be deleted using .remove() on the respective queue. This is working fine on my local machine but leads to an error when it's running in a docker container on Ubuntu:
error: ReplyError: ERR Error running script (call to f_451d4221d6a7ff2251cd0864ab0a28bdba5ea099): @user_script:35: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at parseError (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) {
  command: {
    name: 'evalsha',
    args: [
      '451d4221d6a7ff2251cd0864ab0a28bdba5ea099',
      '10',
      'bull:flow:active',
      'bull:flow:wait',
      'bull:flow:delayed',
      'bull:flow:paused',
      'bull:flow:completed',
      'bull:flow:failed',
      'bull:flow:priority',
      'bull:flow:7',
      'bull:flow:7:logs',
      'bull:flow:limiter',
      '7',
      '32f0c492-4101-4ba0-ae31-4e46bebcfc9b'
    ]
  }
}

I'm a bit lost what's going on as there are explanations regarding the error but nothing in combination with Bull MQ.
